# Change $scope variable from submit() that sends http post request

Tags: angularjs, http, post, submit

I can't set the value for `$scope` in a success response from `$http.post` request. The post request is sent through `submit()` function from a form submit using `ng-submit="submit()"`.

```
chatApp.controller('createController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    $scope.fullname;
    $scope.create = function() {
        // console.log($scope.email, $scope.password, $scope.firstname, $scope.lastname);
        $http.post('ajax/createaccount.php', {
            'email': $scope.email,
            'username': $scope.username,
            'password': $scope.password, 
            'firstname': $scope.firstname, 
            'lastname': $scope.lastname
        }).then(function(data) {
            console.log("Success");
            $scope.fullname = data.config.data.firstname + " " + data.config.data.lastname;
            console.log($scope.fullname);
            $location.path("/createsuccess");
        }, function() {
            console.log("Error");
        })
    }
    console.log($scope.fullname);
}]);
```

The first `console.log($scope.fullname)` outputs the right data.

The second `console.log($scope.fullname)` outputs 'undefined'.

I appreciate everyone who takes the time to look at this.

Comment: The 2nd means one outside the `create` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very basic. An **A**JAX request is an asynchronous request which is executed asynchronously. So when you submit your form using the `$http` method (which is posting data to the server using AJAX), the success callback will be executed after the server responded.

So you can't expect your last `console` statement to execute after your form submission.

```
chatApp.controller('createController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function($scope, $http, $location) {

    console.log("1");
    $scope.fullname;

    $scope.create = function() {
        console.log("2");
        $http.post('ajax/createaccount.php', {
            'email': $scope.email // your data
        }).then(function(data) {
            console.log("3");
        }, function() {
            console.log("Error");
        })

        console.log("4");
    }

    console.log("5");
}]);
```

When your `createController` will instantiate, you will first see the output `1` and then `5`. And when you submit your form using `create()` method, then you will see the output `2` -> `4` and after a few seconds `3`.

**Edit**

To actually fix your issue which you commented, you can use the `$rootScope` but using `$rootScope` is not recommended. So I suggest you create a global controller and assign it to your `body` tag like

```
<body ng-controller="GlobalController">
```

And define an object there:

```
chatApp.controller("GlobalController", ["$scope", function($scope) {

    $scope.globalData = {};
}]);
```

This will create a common Angular scope throughout your application so that you can hold common & generic data. And every child controller (like `createController` in this case) will inherit data from this global controller.

Now, modify your createController code like this:

```
chatApp.controller('createController', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', function ($scope, $http, $location) {

    $scope.create = function () {
        // console.log($scope.email, $scope.password, $scope.firstname, $scope.lastname);
        $http.post('ajax/createaccount.php', {
            'email': $scope.email,
            'username': $scope.username,
            'password': $scope.password,
            'firstname': $scope.firstname,
            'lastname': $scope.lastname
        }).then(function (data) {
            console.log("Success");
            $scope.globalData.fullname = data.config.data.firstname + " " + data.config.data.lastname;
            console.log($scope.fullname);
            $location.path("/createsuccess");
        }, function () {
            console.log("Error");
        })
    };

    console.log($scope.globalData.fullname);
}]);
```

Alternatively, you can create a Angular service/factory to hold the common data.

Comment: Is there anyway, I can set variable $scope.fullname after the request to use it in another page ($location.path("/createsuccess")) that uses the same controller?

Comment: Thank you so much. It's working great. Although may I ask how I could output $scope.globalData.fullname in the new html page that I just redirected? It has the same controller as the redirecting page, "createController". Previously, I did {{ fullname }} and it wasn't working because the data wasn't properly loaded. I appreciate your help.

Comment: It's simple: `{{globalData.fullName}}`

Comment: Thank you so much anyway. You're a legend! :D

Comment: Hehehe!! Great that this helped.

Answer (score 0):

On the `then`of your `$http.post` try updating the following:

```
$scope.fullname = data.config.data.firstname + " " + data.config.data.lastname;
```

to (unless the data object is explicit data.config.data.firstname / WS is not returning data):

```
$scope.fullname = data.firstname + " " + data.lastname;
```

In case this does not solve the problem, try `console.log(data);` to see the `$http.post` method's response from the server.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It doesn't work when I tried. It needs to be in full 'data.config.data.firstname' to access the value returned from the request.

Comment: Can you comment the console.log(data); you get after the request? :)

Comment: 1. Success, asdf asdf (tested values), undefined

Comment: Question, the console inside the .then function is that the one which is not working? In that case please console the .then(function(data) { console.log(data)... If it's the lower console.log please see Shashank Agrawal answer.

Comment: What I try to do is to set $scope.fullname as a value from the response data so that I could use it in another page that uses the same controller as shown in the code ($location.path("/createsuccess")). I'm new to angular. Thank you so much.